# No value was given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtExcel.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    using (var conexao = Conexao())
    {
        conexao.Open();

        string rotaloja = Convert.ToString(dtExcel.Rows[i][1]) + Convert.ToString(dtExcel.Rows[i][0]);
        string bn = "select * from Emb where ROTALOJ= @rotaloja";
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(bn, conexao);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rotaloja", rotaloja);

        using (OleDbCommand Queryyy = new OleDbCommand(bn, conexao))
        {
           using (OleDbDataReader drr = Queryyy.ExecuteReader())
           {
                if (drr.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string cmdText = "UPDATE Emb SET ROTA=@p0, LOJA=@p1, QTDEEMBAL=@p2 where ROTALOJ= @rotaloja";
                        conexao.Open();
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conexao);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", dtExcel.Rows[i][1]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dtExcel.Rows[i][0]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", dtExcel.Rows[i][2]);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (OleDbException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string cmdText = "INSERT INTO Emb (ROTALOJ , ROTA, LOJA, QTDEEMBAL) VALUES (@rotaloja,@p0,@p1,@p2)";
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conexao);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", dtExcel.Rows[i][1]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dtExcel.Rows[i][0]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", dtExcel.Rows[i][2]);
                        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                    catch (OleDbException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

     }           
}
```

I am doing import excel to database more when he does select to see if you have the information in the database is giving error can be? for those who help me thank you

Img : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxQDm.png

Comment: Do not vandalize your query by trying to remove all of its content; such behavior is not appropriate on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a new query `Queryyy` and assumed that the parameters attached with previous query `cmd1` would be available with your command string `bn`. You need to add parameter to your query `Queryyy`

```
using (OleDbCommand Queryyy = new OleDbCommand(bn, conexao))
{
   Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rotaloja", rotaloja); //here
   using (OleDbDataReader drr = Queryyy.ExecuteReader())
  //.......rest of your code
}
```

Consider using helpful variable names.

In your current code, you added parameter to a `cmd1` which is independent of `Queryyy`. In your new query `Queryyy`, you are using command text which requires a parameter and since you are not passing it, you are getting the exception.

Take a look at : [OleDbCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), You may have to pass the parameter with `?`, since it doesn't seem to support named parameters.

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

Comment: @user2966737, did you try using `?` instead of named parameters (`@`) ?

Comment: +  drr null System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the value of `@rotaloja` in this query:

```
"UPDATE Emb SET ROTA=@p0, LOJA=@p1, QTDEEMBAL=@p2 where ROTALOJ= @rotaloja"
```

Answer (score 0):

`OleDBCommand` does not support names parameters.  Replace your parameters with `?` in each SQL statement and add the parameters in the order that they appear in the query.